recommendations for pour-over grinder improvement
I have been using the old Hario Skerton (not pro) ceramic hand grinder for pour over coffee.
I'm not sure of terminology so let me explain what I mean - I use a ceramic cone and filter papers I get from the supermarket, add the ground coffee, and pour recently boiled water over it.
Would getting a Fellow Ode 2 improve my coffee? What about a hand grinder like the Kingridner V6?
I like my coffee to some body, lots of aroma from the extracted oils, and don't like it to be too "tea-like" in consistency.
You may say that what I should do is get an espresso machine but it will take me a long time to save up for that - so the question is ... is an investment in a grinder worth it for my needs?

Any upgrade from a Skerton is worthwhile ;) The Skerton grinds erratically, being more a crusher than a grinder, and it's so. terrifically. slow. On the other hand I suspect a Fellow Ode is more than you need or want.
Knowing little about you, I have to make some guesses. It sounds like your tastes run toward what a coffee hobbyist might describe as — forgive me — uncomplicated coffee. The Ode is more for people who want to tinker with the parameters of their brews, searching for flavour nuances. It has flat burrs for one thing, which may require alignment: partially disassemble, install shims so the flat burrs are precisely parallel.
A Kingrinder would be a big improvement over a Skerton, and the K6 is a particularly nice choice from their lineup. I think you would be pleased with a K6 for a very long time. Timemore is another well-received brand. Personally I use a 1Zpresso hand grinder. Same idea, some improvements.
In electric grinders you'll see the Baratza Encore recommended widely for beginner enthusiasts. I have used and don't like the Encore. I might recommend a Turin SK40 (though not at full suggested retail price!) or a Lagom Mini for you in electric (though I have never used either). If it's the toil of grinding coffee in a Skerton that wears you down, any of these choices will be a refreshing upgrade.
While I'm at it, I might mention the Moka pot for brewing, in case you are unfamiliar. It makes stronger coffee than pour-over, though still weaker than espresso. Personally I prefer pour-over, in a somewhat complicated style.

Thank you - very helpful. As a follow up - what would you say is the difference between a K6 and the 1Zpresso?

if it helps explain my tastes - i love espresso, and strong (less water) americanos, and i also learned to make my own turkish coffee (but i buy it ground )

1Zpressos are a little prettier IMO. I believe the K6 adjustment dial reads 0 at some arbitrary position that can't be adjusted. That's irritating to me but no show stopper. It appears to have the same burr as a 1Zpresso K-series, so probably grinds the same. I would say the K6 is the better value, matching all the important specs of a high-end 1Zpresso.
